# npm install outputs an error: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null

Tags: spfx, npm, yeoman-generator

As instructed within the Setting up your development environment guidance material. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

I've installed yeoman:

`npm install yo --global`

I've reached the last step, to install the sharepoint generator:

`npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint --global`

I'm getting an error reported in the terminal.

`npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null`

Comment: Can you open command prompt and run `npm list -g --depth=0`? Can you share the output, please? Also, what version of node.js are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your NPM version:

```
npm install -g npm@7.24.2
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of another package, I encountered the same problem, but the following command resolved it for me

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Answer (score -1):

The article below answered your question well. Pickalgorithm npm error

https://www.conteudopertinente.com.br/npm/pickalgorithm-npm-error/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/125434)

Comment: The answer to solving the issue is not just executing a command via ssh. This is a complex answer, where rich text and images elucidate the question. That's why I decided to share the link. I believe that if anyone had doubts about the issue at hand, by reading the article, their doubts will be completely resolved.